# ClusterRole in kubernetes with get,list and watch access for all resources

Tags: kubernetes

After listing and getting all the APIs. Some of the APIs are failing for example:-
`

```
Failed to get /apis/apiregistration.k8s.io/v1/apiservices: (403)
Reason: Forbidden
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': 'fcdb2384-efde-4635-981b-4ac21b5d9c51', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid': 'd18a6e91-e91b-4cc4-8be8-a35e84c7fdbf', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid': '76fc0a64-638d-48c8-8add-0a3a60954578', 'Date': 'Fri, 27 Oct 2023 19:25:56 GMT', 'Content-Length': '344'})
HTTP response body: b'{"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"apiservices.apiregistration.k8s.io is forbidden: User \\"test-eks\\" cannot list resource \\"apiservices\\" in API group \\"apiregistration.k8s.io\\" at the cluster scope","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"group":"apiregistration.k8s.io","kind":"apiservices"},"code":403}\n'
```

My CLusterRole is:-

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  # "namespace" omitted since ClusterRoles are not namespaced
  name: cluster-role-read-access
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  #
  # at the HTTP level, the name of the resource for accessing Secret
  # objects is "secrets"
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list", "view"]
```

I tried some things but it is not working. I want a cluster role which is compatible with every api call.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you allowed only `core` API group since in `rules -> apiGroups` you provided empty string. [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.23/#-strong-api-groups-strong-) you can find list of all k8s API groups and you need to provide specific name if you would like to allow some other group.

Example that will allow `core` and

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  # "namespace" omitted since ClusterRoles are not namespaced
  name: cluster-role-read-access
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "apiregistration.k8s.io"]
  #
  # at the HTTP level, the name of the resource for accessing Secret
  # objects is "secrets"
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list", "view"]
```

If you don't want to specify all API's name you can provide wildcard.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  # "namespace" omitted since ClusterRoles are not namespaced
  name: cluster-role-read-access
rules:
- apiGroups: ["*"]
  #
  # at the HTTP level, the name of the resource for accessing Secret
  # objects is "secrets"
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list", "view"]
```